# C#: AppDomain UnhandledException Error

Tags: c#, appdomain, serializable, unhandled-exception

I created an AppDomain and subscribe to event **UnhandledException**

```
AppDomain sandbox1 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("SandBox1");
sandbox1.UnhandledException += 
    new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(sandbox1_UnhandledException);
```

when my code step through UnhandledException subscription, it prompts an error **"Type 'MainUI.MainWindowViewModel' in assembly 'MainUI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable."**

**EDIT:**
So I place Serializable on my MainWindowViewModel class but still it did went through. When I run the application same error goes **"Type 'MainUI.MainWindowViewModel' in assembly 'MainUI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable."**. Please help. Thank you

```
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, 
                    Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.AllFlags)] 
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{......}
```

**EDIT**

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    AppDomain current = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    current.UnhandledException += 
        new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(current_UnhandledException);
}
```

My question here is, if i have 2 appdomain child, how will i know that this exception comes from which child?

Comment: "but still it did not work" - did you get the *same* exception? a *different* exception? or did the screen turn green with pink spots? define "did not work" please. Was it just asking for the base-class to be `[Serializable]`? or...?

Comment: @xscape: I provided you an answer. If you dont follow it, you probably need to experiment with appdomains and remoting a bit more. It is quite hard initially, but a very valuable thing to know.

Answer (score 3):

This is most definitely not the way to do this.

The reason you are getting the error is that the type is trying to cross the appdomain boundary and failing to do so as it is not serializable or a remotable object. This is also something you would not want to happen.

As a solution, you should subscribe to that event within your sandbox appdomain.

Within that handler, you can then transfer the exception info to the 'main' app domain via some remoting interface/service of your choice.

Comment: Hi Leppie, just clarification, if i got it right UnhandledException event must be subscribe to my currentdomain? Please see my edit. How will I know that this exception comes from one of my child domains?